# OpenAI API error: "InvalidRequestError: Invalid URL (POST /v1/classifications)"

Tags: python, curl, classification, openai-api

I'm just playing around with OpenAI API and encountered an issue with the Classification endpoint.

Firstly I uploaded the jsonl file that contains the text, label and metadata for classification training, which was successful:

```
res = openai.File.create(file=open("Classification.jsonl"), purpose = "classifications")
```

```json
{
  "bytes": 1054,
  "created_at": 1672647540,
  "filename": "file",
  "id": "file-9GnLgjFKhSOXOYlSZtPwbJBf",
  "object": "file",
  "purpose": "classifications",
  "status": "uploaded",
  "status_details": null
}
```

Next, I try to query it, as per the guide provided in https://beta.openai.com/docs/guides/classifications

```
openai.Classification.create(
    file="file-9GnLgjFKhSOXOYlSZtPwbJBf",
    query="movie is very good",
    search_model="ada", 
    model="curie", 
    max_examples=3
)
```

Error received:

> InvalidRequestError: Invalid URL (POST /v1/classifications)

Also tried with curl which didn't work as well. Can anyone let me know what is the solution?

What I tried: line by line as per the documentation: https://beta.openai.com/docs/guides/classifications

What I expect to happen: expecting a valid response

What actually resulted: post error, an invalid URL

Answer (score 1):

Classifications API endpoint is deprecated since 3 December 2022.

[image: Deprecated]

As stated in the official [OpenAI article](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/6272941-classifications-transition-guide):

> ​Since releasing the Classifications endpoint in beta last year, we’ve
> developed new methods that achieve better results for this task. **As a
> result, we’ll be removing the Classifications endpoints from our
> documentation and removing access to this endpoint on December 3, 2022
> for all organizations.** New accounts created after June 3rd will not
> have access to this endpoint.

You have the following options:

- [Option 1: Transition to fine-tuning (recommended)](https://beta.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning/classification)
- [Option 2: Transition to Embeddings-based search](https://beta.openai.com/docs/guides/embeddings/use-cases)
- [Option 3: Reimplement existing functionality](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/6272941-classifications-transition-guide)

Comment: Thank you very much and apologies for this, I should have thoroughly check the docs for the API first. Many thanks